# How to automate and get to the end of more command in a Unix script?

Tags: linux, unix

Thanks for your help, I am writing a Unix script to automate a 3rd party script. Inside the 3rd party script I must press the space bar to page down a couple of times and then sign a user agreement, and this happens every time I execute the script. So I wanted to create another Unix program to automatically page down and then once it gets to the "Y/N" then it could just agree automatically.

Listed below is the commands I used but did not work for me:

1. `yes | script_name.sh`
2. `echo "y" | script_name.sh`
3. `script_name.sh | echo "yes"`

Any help would be appreciated thank you again.

Third Party Code:

```
#
# Copy customer.profile to tmp directory
#
if [ -f "${HOME}/customer.profile" ]; then
    cp ${HOME}/customer.profile ${EMC_TMP}/customer.profile
fi

# 
# Copy legal notice to tmp directory
#
cp ${HOME}/EMC_LEGAL_NOTICE.txt ${EMC_TMP}/EMC_LEGAL_NOTICE.txt
```

Comment: I take it that `script_name.sh` is a stand-in for the 3rd party script? It would be helpful if you could provide a pared-down version of that script that does the `more` and any surrounding relevant commands to demonstrate that part of the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: The MORE environment variable can set default options for the `more` command. Helpful options might be `-num <lines>` sets the number of lines in a page and `+num` start displaying at line num. I don't think I have used `more` since the late 1980s but its replacement `less` will ignore input from pipes as a security feature so I imagine a modern more might be the same.

Comment: @StephenP Thanks for helping me Stephen, The actual name of the third party script I am trying to run is called "emcgrab.sh" and it is for a Linux machine. I am providing you with a URL to a basic idea of what the application does it terms of what the user sees. http://raghuramnaidu.blogspot.com/2016/04/how-to-run-emc-grabs-on-linux-machine.html     However, as soon as a launch the script it prompts me to page down just before I get to the line requiring me to accept the terms and copnditions.

Comment: @tharriott you need to include some code in your question as Stephen suggested. Links go dead or get replaced with different content. I'm sure its mentioned in the [help]. What the user sees is not important. The exact invocation of the `more` command is. We can't address what we can't see.

Comment: @NiallCosgrove OK, I provided the  most relevant part of the code from the 3rd party .sh file.I attached it uptop. However, I realize it doesn't say anything with the more command in it. Thought it calls to a txt file called "EMC_LEGAL_NOTICE.txt" where the actual terms of agreement resides.

Comment: @NiallCosgrove Yeah, I figure i am out of luck

Comment: @NiallCosgrove I was thinking I just remove that line of code from the emc.grab.sh script but I don't know if the 3rd party wont accept it without it. It looks as if the answer to it is passed and coped into wherever the output goes.

Comment: I don't understand why you won't show me the code.

Comment: @NiallCosgrove Its not that I don't want to show you, its too long to post.

Comment: @NiallCosgrove lol the struggle of my life

Comment: @NiallCosgrove Thanks anyways for your previous help

Comment: hint: ./emcgrab.sh -h

Comment: @NiallCosgrove Your a scholar thanks, I will takeover from here

Answer (score 1):

Solution depends on the `script_name.sh`. 
I tried the following script:

```
seq 400 | more
read -p "Do you accept? "
echo "Nice, you replied $REPLY"
```

When the `more` is called without path, you can use

```
alias more=: ; echo y |source ./script_name.sh; unalias more
```

Comment: if the OP ran `./emcgrab.sh  -h` he would get command line options to bypass the EULA.  Nice hack using alias btw.